# Android emulator for nativescript don't work

Tags: linux, android-studio, android-emulator, nativescript

I don't know why my Nativescript App don't launch on my android emulator..

More explanation :
I'm on Manjaro (Linux).
I have install android studio and setup environment variable like :

```
JAVA_HOME=/usr/lib/jvm/default
ANDROID_SDK_ROOT=$HOME/Android/Sdk
ANDROID_HOME=$HOME/Android/Sdk
ANDROID_AVD_HOME=$HOME/.android/avd
NPM=$HOME/.npm-global/bin
COMPOSER=$HOME/.config/composer/vendor/bin
export PATH=$PATH:$NPM:$COMPOSER::$ANDROID_SDK_ROOT:$ANDROID_HOME:$ANDROID_AVD_HOME:$ANDROID_HOME/tools:$ANDROID_HOME/platform-tools:$JAVA_HOME
```

After launch my device in emulator of android studio when I make "tns run android --emulator" 
this append :

```
✖ The ANDROID_HOME environment variable is not set or it points to a non-existent directory. You will not be able to perform any build-related operations for Android.
 To be able to perform Android build-related operations, set the `ANDROID_HOME` variable to point to the root of your Android SDK installation directory.

✖ WARNING: adb from the Android SDK is not installed or is not configured properly.
 For Android-related operations, the NativeScript CLI will use a built-in version of adb.
To avoid possible issues with the native Android emulator, Genymotion or connected
Android devices, verify that you have installed the latest Android SDK and
its dependencies as described in http://developer.android.com/sdk/index.html#Requirements

✖ Cannot find a compatible Android SDK for compilation. To be able to build for Android, install Android SDK 28.
 Run `$ sdkmanager` to manage your Android SDK versions.

✖ You need to have the Android SDK Build-tools installed on your system. You can install any version in the following range: '>=23 <=28'.
 Run `$ sdkmanager` from your command-line to install required `Android Build Tools`. In case you already have them installed, make sure `ANDROID_HOME` environment variable is set correctly.

✖ Error executing command 'javac'. Make sure you have installed The Java Development Kit (JDK) and set JAVA_HOME environment variable.
 You will not be able to build your projects for Android.
To be able to build for Android, verify that you have installed The Java Development Kit (JDK) and configured it according to system requirements as
 described in http://docs.nativescript.org/setup/ns-cli-setup/ns-setup-linux.html#system-requirements

✖ WARNING: The Java Development Kit (JDK) is not installed or is not configured properly.
```

I don't know why..

Comment: Did you make sure your bash profile is loaded and the components are accessible? Try hitting commands like `adb` / `java` in your console.

Comment: SO, now android is installed properly. But now it's JAVA_HOME the problem.. `export JAVA_HOME=/usr/lib/jvm/java-8-openjdk` .. and it's not working.. and i'm sure java open jdk 8 is installed